# Sharepoint list column order is reversed in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Because of that problem, I usually use Internet Explorer.

Everything is set to be right to left [using different language] and so the columns order is from rtl.

When opening in chrome, only the list's columns are from ltr and everything else seems ok.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

List.Direction property may help you .

check the link :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95981/issue-with-list-schema-what-is-direction